# how can I keep my program from continuing past a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

So I have a timer that calls itself recursively:

```
function introAnimation()
{
    var ostream = document.getElementById('table');

    var newhtml = '<h1>Ready?</h1><br/>';
    newhtml += '<h1>' + countdown-- + '</h1>';

    ostream.innerHTML = newhtml;

    if (countdown > 0)
        var a = setTimeout(function() {introAnimation()}, 1000);

}
```

but the issue is that the program continues to run before it finishes the timer. Is there any way to keep all other processes from going until the specified function stops?

Comment: consider using an IFRAME ? keep the `setTimeout` code at parent frame ?

Comment: What do you mean by the program? If it is initiated by a function, you can call it after the countdown by using an `else` statement.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: How about having your intro animation on a different page and redirecting after it is finished?

Comment: My program continues to execute code after the setTimeout is started, but I want it to wait until the timer is done before continuing. how would I do that?

Comment: What is your program? Can you clarify that?

Comment: @user2419560: No, you cannot. "*Keeping all other process from going*" would effectively freeze your browser, which is absolutely undesired.

Comment: I'm creating a memory game and I want a timer animation to go off before the game starts, but when I use the setInterval it keeps running and the grid for my table gets overridden by the timer that keeps going off. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to keep all other processes from going until the specified function stops?

Yes and no. The way would be an infinite loop (`while(true) ;`), but that is undesired because it will freeze your browser and *never* stop (since the timeout cannot intercept a running function). So you *should* not. What you actually want to ask for is:

> How can I defer my program to continue after a timeout?

Use a callback. You already have used that in your `introAnimation`, so it shouldn't be hard. Change that function to

```
function introAnimation(callback) {
    var ostream = document.getElementById('table');

    var newhtml = '<h1>Ready?</h1><br/>';
    newhtml += '<h1>' + countdown-- + '</h1>';

    ostream.innerHTML = newhtml;

    if (countdown > 0)
        var a = setTimeout(function() {introAnimation(callback)}, 1000);
    else
        callback();
}
```

and your program from

```
introAnimation();
// rest of program
```

to

```
introAnimation(function() {
    // part of the program that should run when the itro is done
});
// part of the programm that runs during the intro animation
// (might be nothing)
```

Comment: I did the first part and it's still behaving as it did before. And how would i do that last part if the program is just an external js file that runs when the user presses a button?

Comment: Yeah, both parts are essential :-) Just run the external file in the callback of the intro.

Comment: if the external js file executes directly you should change it so that you can call a function that will executes the script.

Comment: So if I have a button on the html document that executes a startUp() function that starts the whole process I should rename it to introAnimation(function() {...});
right?

Comment: No, you should not rename it. You should put it in the callback: `introAnimation(startUp);`